# HTML5 URL (clicktag) with variables

Tags: html, url, clicktag

I would like to use HTML5 banners in my company,

I have implemented this script with dynamic variables (I use this URL for flash\gif banners):

```
stage.setFlashVars("
    clickTAG=http://www.avatrade.com/lp/bonus100-button?tag=_ADPLDCP(Tag:)_
    &tag2=_ADPLDCP(ws_name:)_-EN-100bonusF15-_ADPLDCP(pl_size:)_-100bonusF15-B-_ADPLDCP(Page:)_-");
```

But when I click the banner I get this URL:

```
http://www.avatrade.com/lp/bonus100-button?tag=_ADPLDCP(Tag:)_
```

Do you have any idea why I loose the variables after the character "&"?

Comment: Your URL is invalid. You have to `urlescape()` some characters as always when you create parts of a URL. Some characters have special meaning inside a URL.

Comment: And please fix the formatting of your question so taht thigns get readable. Thanks.

Comment: it's not invalid URL - my platform can read these variables, i use the same URL for gif\flash banners, my question is: Why the URL cut after the character "&"?

Comment: As said above: it might work in some cases, since platforms try to tolerate faults. That does not mean it is a valid URL. I suspect that your issue with the missing arguments is exactly cause by that invalid URL.

Comment: This would be a valid version or your URL, have a try with that: `http://www.avatrade.com/lp/bonus100-button?tag=_ADPLDCP%28Tag%3A%29_&tag2=_ADPLDCP%28ws_name%3A%29_-EN-100bonusF15-_ADPLDCP%28pl_size%3A%29_-100bonusF15-B-_ADPLDCP%28Page%3A%29_-`

Comment: Oh, and at least in your post you have a line break right before the `&`...